# Laravel Login and Register works locally, but doesn't work after it deployed to the web

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have been trying to figure it out why is it happening? I made the generic laravel login with php artisan make:auth, it works perfectly on my local machine. I deployed my app online today, Login and register gives me an error. I google that error mostly its related to mail services but Login and Register is nothing to do with Mail. Can anyone please direct me to a right direction. In a log file error is quite large. Here are the some lines of error error:-

> production.ERROR: Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530 5.7.1 Authentication required " {"exception":"[object] (Swift_TransportException(code: 530): Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530 5.7.1 Authentication required " at /var/www/laravel/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php:419) [stacktrace] #0 /var/www/laravel/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php(317): Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->assertResponseCode('530 5.7.1 Authe...', Array) #1 /var/www/laravel/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/EsmtpTransport.php(272): Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->executeCommand('MAIL FROM:executeCommand('MAIL FROM:doMailFromCommand('hello@example.c...') #4 /var/www/laravel/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php(480): Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->doMailTransaction(Object(Swift_Message), 'hello@example.c...', Array, Array) #5 /var/www/laravel/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php(189): Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->sendTo(Object(Swift_Message), 'hello@example.c...', Array, Array) #6 /var/www/laravel/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Mailer.php(73): Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->send(Object(Swift_Message), Array) #7 /var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailer.php(464): Swift_Mailer->send(Object(Swift_Message), Array) #8 /var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailer.php(248): Illuminate\Mail\Mailer->sendSwiftMessage(Object(Swift_Message)) #9 /var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailable.php(148): Illuminate\Mail\Mailer->send('emails.contact', Array, Object(Closure))

Comment: Show full stack trace of your errors. And, please, describe when it happens: when user is trying to login?

Comment: Those errors look like it is trying to send a confirmation email to `hello@example.com` using SwiftMailer. Do you have any settings inside your `config/mail.php` file? Maybe post your login and register methods.

Comment: I changed my env to production from development, so all the stack trace is in the log file. When I try to login or register new user Laravel app throws a generic error "Whoops, looks like something went wrong." . I can post the whole log file if that helps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your application is trying to send an email `emails.contact` to `hello@example.com`. The `Authentication required` error may indicate that your smtp info is wrong.

I would recommend looking into MailGun and using that as a driver for your mail. Its free (does require card details) for up to 10,000 emails a month (or something like that). You can see what emails are being sent and who is receiving them or not, and it almost guarantees delivery to the Inbox rather than Spam.

https://www.mailgun.com/

Its easy to set up and you can easily configure it with your Laravel application. Take a look at the docs here, the information you need is right at the top of the article. It's a matter of 3 variables :)

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mail

Remember to run `php artisan config:cache` after you're done setting up your config.

Comment: Hi TPHughes, I have updated all the Mail setting, now I'm getting another error :- SQLSTATE[HY000] [1698] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' {"exception":"[object] (PDOException(code: 1698): SQLSTATE[HY000] [1698] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' at /var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php

Comment: That means that the database credentials are wrong. Check your .env file has the correct settings to connect to your MySQL database.

Comment: I think I have a problem with Ubuntu 18.04, When I installed MySQL it did not ask for a root password and let me use MySQL without password. I have moved everything to Ubuntu 16.04, it asked me to set MySQL password. Now I ran into another problem because in Ubuntu 16.04 it installed php 7.0 and my project is in laravel 5.6 that require php 7.1 or above. Now I upgrade the php to 7.2 after that I ran composer install --no-dev its giving me a syntax error.

Comment: What is the syntax error? What happens if you use the command `mysql -u root -p` in the terminal? Type the password you set in 16.04 and hit enter. Update your question with the new information and the fact that you've made it past the Mail error.

Comment: I have managed to make it work, I deleted the both ubuntu 18.04 and 16.04 servers. I reinstall everything on new Ubuntu 16.04 and install the php7.2 to start with and everything just fall in place like lego pieces. Thanks for you guidance, I really appreciate it . Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

create a email account in your online server,
then
config your the email account setting in app.
use this files: **.env** , **config\mail.php**

Comment: Sorry I am new to laravel, In fact I'm new to php. I think I got what you are trying to say. If you please guide me to right direction where I can do some research to figure it out? I will appreciate  you, cheers!

Comment: ok,can you create an email account in your online host?
if no, What control panel do you use for host?(like: cpanel,directadmin,plesk...)

Comment: I'm using vultr for hosting my app, I am not using any cpanel or similar services. I found a great tutorial online that help me deploy my webapp online manually - https://devmarketer.io/learn/deploy-laravel-5-app-lemp-stack-ubuntu-nginx/ . Is there any free mail sending services to just test it out?